# Error when exporting collection in mongodb to csv

Tags: mongodb, csv, export, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to export a specific collection in the mongodb to a csv file. I just the default function `Collection`  and `Export collection` in the tool bar. After select the field and the destination of the csv file and click the export button, I got an error which is `EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\gnuhg\Desktop\School.csv'` 
And I try to run the mongodb compass in administrator mode but still not success.

Comment: May be the `School.csv` already exists and is in use?

Comment: there are no such a csv file in my desktop

Comment: The feature worked fine on my Widows PC with Compass 1.21.2 and MongoDB v4.2.8.